# Let $n\geq 1$ and let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix with real entries such that $A^k=O$, then find value of $\det(I+A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Let $n\geq 1$ and let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix with real entries such that $A^k=O$, for some $k\geq 1$. Let $I$ be the $n\times n$ identity matrix. Then find value of $\det(I+A)$ .

**My Attempt**

Since $A^k=O$ we have $\det(A)=0$ and also $A^k=A^{k+1}=A^{k+2}=...=O$

Let $p\in \Bbb N$ where $p\geq k$

$(I+A)^p=I+\binom{p}{1}A+\binom{p}{2}A^2+...+\binom{p}{k-1}A^{k-1}+O$
(since $A^k=A^{k+1}=A^{k+2}=...=O$)

$A^{k-1}(I+A)^p=A^{k-1}$

$\det(A^{k-1}(I+A)^p)=\det(A^{k-1})=0$

I wonder if I am doing right because I cannot justify further steps

Comment: $A^{k-1}(I+A)^p=A^{k-1}$; I didn't get this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

> If $A$ is nilpotent, then $p(\lambda) = \det(\lambda I - A) = \lambda^n$.

**Further hint:**

> What will happen if you plug in $\lambda = -1$ into both forms of $p(\lambda)$?